# how to set a listener on a function's result?

Tags: java, android, event-handling

i have been coding in android for a while, an now i am working on an app project which sets company flights and the number of passengers to take the flight, i have a form activity where i enter all the info about the flight like date_of_flight,flight_code,airport,flight_type(departure or arrival) every thing works for this first form an when i click the submit button another activity opens where i have to set the passengers of the flight.

On this activity i have an `editText` view that accepts only numbers an the number you enter defines the number of passengers on the flight you just registered, depending on this number small forms that take in passenger name and id will appear below the `editText` now my problem is in my `activity.java` i have a function `"getPassenger_pop"` that is in charge of collecting the number entered by the user then what i want to do is set some event listener that will continually check the result of the `getPassenger_pop` function an then automatically print out a number of custom forms to get the passengers info

is it possible to set a custom listener on a function's result if that is possible pls can someone show me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using notifications. But better would be pass a handler/delegate whose function can be called when desired values is updates. In setter of desired property you can call function from handler.